# Update multiple records using a single query for performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I am having an update query inside a loop which get executed thousands of times.

All goes well but problem is that it takes lot of time for all updates.

If I concatenate/combine all update queries in a single string like this:

```
$update_query = "";
while(condition)
{
    $update_query = $update_query  . " update table set ... ; ";
}
```

Then execute *$update_query* single time, will it be helpful?

Or what else I can do for better performance? Any hint or suggestion?

Comment: Make sure you are using row-level locking (storage engine is innodb or other with row-level locking, myisam doesn't have such) and you have an index in your where clause (in the best case - an unique index). Also you may turn off autocommit, and commit at once ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES (1, 'value1'), (2, 'value2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
value = VALUES(value)
```

Comment: Sounds good! Will it check duplication of primary key or duplication of whole row?

Comment: @Vitthal it will check for duplication of any unique index, not of whole row

Comment: @Darhazer thanks! And this worked for me. It is much faster than normal multiple updates.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a batch update query, something like:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = CASE other_field
    WHEN 1 THEN 'value'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'value'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'value'
END 
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: This will be good but I have thousands of records and each update will update multiple columns, in this case it will become difficult.